# Are sessions and cookies generally considered inputs?

Tags: php, input

I consider `$_GET` and `$_POST` to be input in a web application written in PHP. That's because they contain values that the user can define and that "comes" along with the HTTP request. But are sessions and cookies the same?

This question came to me when I was reading the wikipedia PHP italian page that says that common inputs are `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for input you mean "all the things coming in the request" (so, things that need validation, etc.), you should include:

- POST/GET vars (`$_POST`, `$_GET`)
- Cookies (`$_COOKIE`)
- The request path (`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`)
- The HTTP method (`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`)
- The HTTP headers (usually in `$_SERVER["HTTP_"*]`)

The session is a special case since all the session variables are stored on the server-side, i.e. the user cannot modify them as it would with cookies. Anyways, a single cookie is saved on the client-side to store the session ID, that can be reset / set to a custom value by the user.

### Update - about `$_REQUEST`

As pointed out, in PHP you also have access to `$_REQUEST`, that is a mix of variables from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`.
The exact content of `$_REQUEST` is determined by the `request_order` directive in `php.ini`.

Comment: I think this better, i wasn't fond of the saying "input". I think it's better represented as the request.

Comment: I'd add the [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) page to that answer.

Comment: Yeah, REQUEST is a mix of GET + POST + COOKIES

Comment: what do you consider "input" in a web application?

Comment: "input" is usually meant as "everything coming from the user", as in the list in my answer above. But "input" could also come from files, server-side-opened sockets, etc..

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` only contains what you yourself put there. `$_COOKIE`, however, should be considered untrusted user input along with `$_GET, $_POST`.

The one point of crossover I can think of is an end user attempting to supply a crafted `PHPSESSID` via `$_COOKIE` in hopes of gaining access to another user's session.

Unless you directly store other input `($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE)` into `$_SESSION`, it can be trusted.

```
// Oops, $_SESSION['someval'] now holds unfiltered user input!
$_SESSION['someval'] = $_POST['someval'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Session data can't be directly input by the user unless you have created this functionality within your application somewhere; such as:

```
$_SESSION['lastSearch'] = $_GET['search'];
```

If your application does have functionality similar to this, or if you aren't sure; I would still filter/sanitize your data becore printing it to the page or using it in a SQL statement. Its better to be safe than sorry.

However, cookie data can be altered easily and is considered direct INPUT.

Answer (score 0):

php has a global variable called $_REQUEST *An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE*

The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET, POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by the remote user and cannot be trusted.

The values defined in $_REQUEST are defined by the user, in the browser.

Variables in $_SESSION can't be modified by the browser. They are only modified by php, and generally they can be considered trusted.